# Do these two expressions mean the same?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

So for a given database we have the sets Persons, Married, Women, Men and Children.

I want to express all Women who are not Children and not Married:

$$Women\setminus \left ( married \cup children \right )$$
$$Women \setminus \left ( \overline{married} \cap \overline{children} \right )$$

Do these set operations qualify as Women who are not Children or Married, and express the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, both give you the set you want and they are equivalent by the [De Morgan's laws](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: Thank you, Dennis. Did I use the correct notation for stating not married and children? That is "~"

Comment: The notations you used are unusual: usually one uses $\setminus$ for substruction of sets and either $A^c$ or $\bar{A}$ for the compliment of $A$.

Comment: I edited my initial question according to your corrections. Thank you for your help!